# Letsencrypt ImportError: No module named interface on amazon linux while renewing

Tags: python, linux, lets-encrypt

**Today when i tried to renew my certificates using this command I'm facing error**

```
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew --config /etc/letsencrypt/config.ini --agree-tos && apachectl graceful
```

**also tried this command**

```
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew
```

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 7, in <module>
    from certbot.main import main
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    import zope.component
  File "/root/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/component/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from zope.interface import Interface
ImportError: No module named interface
```

**I did lot of research no solution found.**

Comment: ? May be *you* can guess, which python-[??] to use. I.e. lots of packages with `interface.py` https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=interface.py

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**After doing lots of research I found it.**

You have to unset Python install layout

```
 unset PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT
```

then update letsencrypt

```
 /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto -v
```

for more refer this blog https://o-mkar.com/facing-problem-while-renewing-letsencrypt-certificates-importerror-no-module-named-interface-amazon-linux

Comment: I also have to uninstall zope.interface and reinstall it, along with cryptography.

Comment: Another method to try if you are still getting errors after unset the environment variable is to remove the python virtualenv that gets created under your home folder in .local. Once purging that folder the reinstall to newest version went smoothly

Comment: But what are the implications of unsetting that environment variable? Should you re-set it?

Answer (score 4):

`sudo pip uninstall zope.interface` and reinstall zope.interface

`sudo pip install zope.interface`

Comment: For me, `zope.interface` was not installed, but installing didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and upgrading pip and virtualenv as instructed in this [post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/letsencrypt-auto-certonly-d-domainname-gives-error-importerror-no-module-named-interface/13991/12) worked for me.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
rm -rf ~/.local/share/letsencrypt
/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto --debug
```

Comment: My system reports 'Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages"

Answer (score 0):

Part of the issue for me was related to some strange default behavior around 64 bit packages installing, but not being picked up by python.  After getting this issue [it's mostly installed at this point], run the following [assuming it tries to install in /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/]

```
cd /root/.local/share/letsencrypt
\cp -r ./venv/lib64/* ./venv/lib/
```

Then retry the command.  The install locations of the python virtual environment change with different versions and operating systems, but the general principle has helped me debug two different installs.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, else zope and cryptography kept showing the dependency of install into each other leading to a deadlock. See [Git Repo](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2544#issuecomment-505196160)

```
sudo /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/bin/pip install cryptography interface zope
```