# letsencrypt failed with ImportError: No module named proxy

Tags: python, lets-encrypt, certbot, amazon-linux

This seems to be vaguely similar to another question, ["Letsencrypt failed with ImportError: No module named interface,"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42734006/letsencrypt-failed-with-importerror-no-module-named-interface) since it's a similar error message, on "Amazon Linux AMI," except that in this case, it's a different module ("proxy" instead of "interface"), and some of what the other question refers to doesn't even exist. And the other question was back in 2017.

I had certbot-auto working. But two days later, when I found the problems that had been interfering with the DNS challenge (I'd manually put in part of the name that was already being put in automatically), and made another attempt to get a wildcard cert, certbot promptly broke.

**When I entered the command (names changed to protect the innocent):**

```
certbot-auto certonly --manual --preferred-challenges DNS -d 'foo.bar.net,*.foo.bar.net'
```

**it produced this output:**

```
Upgrading certbot-auto 1.0.0 to 1.1.0…
Replacing certbot-auto…
Creating virtual environment…
Installing Python packages…
Installation succeeded.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt”, line 7, in
from certbot.main import main
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py”, line 2, in
from certbot._internal import main as internal_main
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py”, line 10, in
import josepy as jose
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/josepy/init.py”, line 41, in
from josepy.interfaces import JSONDeSerializable
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/josepy/interfaces.py”, line 7, in
from josepy import errors, util
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/josepy/util.py”, line 7, in
import OpenSSL
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/init.py”, line 8, in
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py”, line 12, in
from cryptography import x509
ImportError: No module named cryptography
```

I then tried the solution given [here, for "No module named cryptography" in Amazon Linux 2](https://www.bantrain.com/how-to-fix-letsencrypt-upgrade-error-in-amazon-linux-2/?doing_wp_cron=1579566948.4891788959503173828125), but when I entered the final command in that solution,

```
/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/bin/pip install cryptography interface
```

it complained with

```
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py”, line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py”, line 335, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py”, line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py”, line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py”, line 666, in _prepare_file
check_dist_requires_python(dist)
File “/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/packaging.py”, line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
feed_parser.feed(metadata)
File “/usr/lib64/python2.7/email/feedparser.py”, line 177, in feed
self._input.push(data)
File “/usr/lib64/python2.7/email/feedparser.py”, line 99, in push
parts = data.splitlines(True)
AttributeError: ‘NoneType’ object has no attribute ‘splitlines’
```

Then, when I tried the original command,

```
certbot-auto certonly --manual --preferred-challenges DNS -d 'foo.bar.net,*.foo.bar.net'
```

I got

```
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt", line 7, in <module>
    from certbot.main import main
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from certbot._internal import main as internal_main
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    import zope.component
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/component/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from zope.component.interfaces import IComponentArchitecture
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/component/interfaces.py", line 21, in <module>
    import zope.deferredimport
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/deferredimport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from zope.deferredimport.deferredmodule import initialize
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/deferredimport/deferredmodule.py", line 18, in <module>
    import zope.proxy
ImportError: No module named proxy
```

I looked at the "No module named interface" question, but where it asks to do things with

```
/root/.local/share/letsencrypt
```

I can't find any such directory as "/root/.local" nor "/home/ec2-user/.local" nor "/.local"; if I go to the file system root and do

```
find -name letsencrypt
```

I get

```
./var/lib/letsencrypt
./var/log/letsencrypt
./etc/letsencrypt
./opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/letsencrypt
./opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt
./opt/trac-1.2.3-11/letsencrypt
```

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: Try creating a new virtualenv and then `pip install certbot` into it. There are probably a number of issues during the package upgrade with certain nested dependencies not correctly resolved and/or certain namespace packages were not installed correctly due to possible old (buggy) versions of setuptools being used when installing the `zope.proxy` package.

Comment: "virtualenv"? Are we talking another instance, or something within the instance, that I just don't know about yet?

Comment: [Create a new `venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) like you have in `./opt/eff.org/certbot/venv`, but put it at a different location.

Comment: Or heck, follow the instructions in the accepted answer in the question you've linked.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it following the next steps

1. Download certbot-auto by going to [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-ami.html#lets-encrypt-alami).
2. Delete letsencrypt folder:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /opt/eff.org/
   ```
3. Install cryptography module:

   ```
   sudo python -m pip install cryptography
   ```
4. Run certbot-auto --debug

   ```
   sudo ./certbot-auto --debug
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not dead sure, but I believe this is the one I for which I ultimately did an "end run" around the problem, using Lego (which came with the Bitnami stack, and is Bitnami's preferred LE interface program for this OS) instead of Certbot.