# Let's Encrypt no interface issue

Tags: lets-encrypt

I am on AWS Ec2 Amazon Linux and trying to use Let's Encrypt. When I first installed Let's Encrypt couple month back I did not have any issues renewing the certificates. But now I receive this error and not able to renew.

```
# ./certbot-auto --debug
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt", line 7, in <module>
    from certbot.main import main
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import zope.component
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zope/component/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from zope.interface import Interface
ImportError: No module named interface
```

I have tried  unset `PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT` and upgrading pip,virtualenv. No luck.

It seems to be simialr to this issue [Letsencrypt ImportError: No module named interface on amazon linux while renewing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170100/letsencrypt-importerror-no-module-named-interface-on-amazon-linux-while-renewin) But dirctory is different. Not sure I want to rm the `/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I hit exactly this issue just now with Amazon Linux. The fix that worked for me is [detailed on the certbot GitHub issue](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2823#issuecomment-292004488)

> I had the same issue from what appears to be a bad install of certbot.
>   I fixed it by running the following:
>
> ```
> unset PYTHON_INSTALL_LAYOUT
> /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/pip install --upgrade certbot
> ```

I did not have pip installed separately on the server, it was only available as part of the certbot install, so this was the only way I could use pip to upgrade the installation properly.

Comment: Thank that fixed it!

Comment: This was a savior. Had struggled for hours.

Answer (score 34):

I was able to fix this problem with:

```
sudo rm -rf /root/.local/share/letsencrypt/

sudo rm -rf /opt/eff.org/certbot/
```

Then rerun certbot-auto in user mode (ec2-user).

```
./certbot-auto renew -v --debug
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer! Thanks.

Comment: After this I got an error about hazmat something something not found error. I fixed this with comment by "mrballcb" here https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/1680#issuecomment-358728515

Comment: Worked after a migration from Ubuntu server 16.04 to 18.04.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my 18.04 as well

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pip` installed on your EC2 instance as I do, you can simply do this:

```
rm -rf /opt/eff.org/*
pip install -U certbot
certbot renew --debug
```

Downloading `certbot-auto` via `wget` has always caused problems for me, so the above method is preferred.